# Notepad++: Delete line before specific text on next line

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I would like to filter my list and delete all my free subscriptions including the line above it `Membership No: Random Number`. Is there any way of doing this?

---

Sample data:

```
Membership No: Random Number
Subscription: Free
Membership No: Random Number
Subscription: Free
Membership No: Random Number
Subscription: Paid
Membership No: Random Number
Subscription: Free
Membership No: Random Number
Subscription: Free
```

Comment: Can you give example of what you have now, and what your desired output is? And why do you include [microsoft-excel] in your tags?

Comment: If your question is "How many Paid strings are there", the answer is: Use the "Count" feature in Notepad++. It will provide the answer. Ctrl+F, Search for Paid, press Count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assume: The file uses Linux EOL (LF), as the post has `linux` tag

1. Search > Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>)

   - **Find what:** `^.*\nSubscription: Free\n`
   - **Replace with:**  (empty)
   - **Search mode:** Regular expression
   - Untick ". matches newline"
2. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. Two lines will be removed for each match

---

- `^` : Beginning of line
- `.*` : Matches any string (the line before the key string)
- `\n` : Linux line break
- `Subscription: Free` : Key string
- `\n` : Linux line break

Comment: Thanks for this but this deletes all other text, rather than deleting the above line and the searched line.

Comment: Untick ". matches newline", and try again. Answer updated accordingly.